# All events showing everyday

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, fullcalendar

I'm using Fullcalendar to show events, however, it's showing all events on every day, regardless of date, as you can see below.

How do I stop this from happening and just have the calendar show the events correctly?

[image]

My code on my page 'calendar.php' is:

```
$(function() {
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        themeSystem: 'bootstrap3',
        allDaySlot: 'false',
        firstDay: '1',

        header: {
            left: 'prev, today, next',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month, agendaWeek, agendaDay'
        },

        defaultView: 'month',

        views: {
            month: {
                columnHeaderFormat: 'dddd'
            },
            agendaWeek: {
                titleFormat: 'MMMM YYYY',
                columnHeaderFormat: 'dddd Do'
            },

            agendaDay: {
                titleFormat: 'MMMM YYYY',
                columnHeaderFormat: 'dddd Do'
            },
        },

        minTime: '09:00',
        editable: 'true',
        eventLimit: 'true',
        selectable: 'true',
        events: 'events.php'
    });
});
```

and the code for 'events.php' is:

```
$connect = new PDO('mysql: host=localhost; dbname=dbName', 'userName', 'pWord');

$data = array();

$query = "SELECT bookingEnquiryNumber, IFNULL(NULLIF(groupName,''),CONCAT(firstName,' ',lastName)) AS bookingName, bookingDate, bookingStartTime, bookingFinishTime FROM tblbookingdetails WHERE accepted = 1 ORDER BY bookingDate";

$statement = $connect->prepare($query);

$statement->execute();

$result = $statement->fetchAll();

foreach($result as $row)
    {
        $data[] = array(
            'title'    => $row["bookingName"],
            'date'     => $row["bookingDate"],
            'start'    => $row["bookingStartTime"],
            'end'      => $row["bookingFinishTime"]
        );
    }

echo json_encode($data);
```

The output from 'events.php' is:

```
[{"title":"Jacquenette Reichhardt","date":"2018-10-07","start":"20:00","end":"22:00"},{"title":"Haag Group","date":"2018-10-09","start":"13:00","end":"15:00"},{"title":"Nelly Tuffs","date":"2018-10-18","start":"16:00","end":"18:00"},{"title":"Aufderhar, Beatty and Anderson","date":"2018-10-22","start":"12:00","end":"14:00"},{"title":"Moore Inc","date":"2018-10-31","start":"19:00","end":"22:00"},{"title":"Ledner, Farrell and DuBuque","date":"2018-11-01","start":"19:00","end":"22:00"},{"title":"Stamm, Nicolas and Lind","date":"2018-11-04","start":"17:00","end":"19:00"},{"title":"Elvina Barnet","date":"2018-11-15","start":"10:00","end":"13:00"},{"title":"Hegmann, Armstrong and Leffler","date":"2018-11-21","start":"17:00","end":"19:00"},{"title":"Chrisy Laurie","date":"2018-11-24","start":"17:00","end":"19:00"},{"title":"Sasha Andrysek","date":"2018-12-07","start":"16:00","end":"20:00"},{"title":"Littel-Daniel","date":"2018-12-11","start":"09:00","end":"17:00"}]
```

I used some of the code from [Jquery Fullcalendar Integration with PHP and Mysql](https://www.webslesson.info/2017/12/jquery-fullcalandar-integration-with-php-and-mysql.html).

My calendar page is uses MySQLi to connect to the database but 'events.php' uses PDO (I can't get Mysqli to work).

Comment: I guess you need to send an `id` also.

Comment: @FelippeDuarte. Just tried that and has made no difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lookin at the docs, there is no `date` only `start` and `end`.
So, replace

```
    $data[] = array(
        'title'    => $row["bookingName"],
        'date'     => $row["bookingDate"],
        'start'    => $row["bookingStartTime"],
        'end'      => $row["bookingFinishTime"]
    );
```

With

```
    $date = $row["bookingDate"];
    $data[] = array(
        'title'    => $row["bookingName"],
        'start'    => $date. ' ' .$row["bookingStartTime"].':00',
        'end'      => $date. ' ' .$row["bookingFinishTime"].':00'
    );
```

Or do the equivalent using MySql to send `start` and `end` as datetime with format `YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss`

Comment: Thanks for this. The code doesn't seem to work and just shows a blank calendar, however, using your idea of manipulating MySQL fields did the trick. I used CONCAT_WS to join the relevant fields and it did the trick. Many thanks.